# Disable visual studio's cache

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Can we turn off the process of making **Asp.net temporary files** and **project assemblies cache** to
be sure that the results we get are really fresh and they got all the latest changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a web site (File->New Web Site), or a Web Application Project (File->New Project)?

If it's a web application project, then rebuilding it should be enough. I don't know whether web sited have a concept of a rebuild.

Also, you can just check the dates of the temporary files to see if they're correct.

Comment: Thanks john again for participating my questions , I usually use Web Application projects , I'll use your advice , Is it really enough for example when we have a project contained of several other projects ?
Don't we need any cleaning or re-referencing the assemblies ?

Comment: No, nothing else. "Rebuild" is the same as "Clean" + "Build". References never need to change.

Comment: Some of the project assemblies are loaded into visual studio during design-time. Any of these that are managed code will unlikely be able to be unloaded from the AppDomain and therefore will not be able to be unloaded until visual studio is closed unless the appdomain is not the default and is unloaded itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check all of the files in your project, and make sure that none of them have a date/time stamp in the future.  This confuses the compiler. To check date time stamps, [use the Details view in Windows Explorer](http://www.theeldergeek.com/applying_detail_view_to_windows.htm), and examine the *Date Modified* column.

If you are still dissatisfied with the results, [use the command-line compiler](http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/417.aspx).  The command-line compiler does not have access to the Visual Studio cache; it is forced to use your project files that are saved to disk.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET website model mandates that any changed pages are automatically recompiled when requested. If those are class files (App_Code) or assemblies in the Bin folder, they would be compiled (former category) and updated to the Temporary files location upon the first subsequent request to the application.

So, I do not see any reason why the response should not be "fresh". The only case that seems possible is that you have caching enabled (at the client or the server end) and the response to the client is not really using the latest data.

Comment: Sometimes it happened for me that I couldn't see the latest changes ,
Usually I work in projects that contains other projects inside itself ,
and I wanted to be sure that every changes that I made will effect . thatnks for your advice